# 'find' command giving : No such file or directory error in shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script to check the disk usage and list the files larger than 1MB in the path input by the user.

```
#!/bin/bash
DISK_USAGE=$(df -h /dev/xvda1 | awk '{gsub("%","");print $5}' | tail -1)

THRESHOLD=80

       
 if [ $DISK_USAGE -ge $THRESHOLD ]
 then

                read -p  "Enter the path for log files: " PATH
                echo "Below is the list of large log files which are taking space:"
                echo $("find $PATH -type f -size +1M")
 fi
```

Below is the output of this script:

```
Enter the path for log files: /var/log
Below is the list of large files which are taking space:
./sample-script.sh: line 17: find /var/log -type f -size +1M: No such file or directory
```

For some reason find command is not able to pick any path that I enter as an input.

What could be a possible reason and the solution?

Comment: How are you sure there are files bigger than 1M in `/var/log` ?

Comment: @alecxs Use \`backticks\` to put stuff in monospace font, like: `echo $("find $PATH -type f -size +1M")` and `find "$PATH" -type f -size +1M`.

Comment: @KamilCuk @alecxs I am getting below output using your solution:
`Enter the path for log files: /var/log Below is the list of large files which are taking space: ./list-large-files: line 12: find: command not found `

Comment: @alecxs even if I store the output of find command in a variable instead of echoing it, I am getting the same error.

Comment: That is because you are using system reserved variable name `PATH`. If your core utils do not provide `find` this is another issue. type *'which find'* to double check it is in path or *'realpath $(which find)'* to double check it's a binary or busybox symlink. If the output throws error it does not exist or you messed up path. refer to jhnc's answer for correct usage

Comment: @alecxs changing the variable name has helped. Now I am getting the desired output. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    echo $("find $PATH -type f -size +1M")
```

This attempts to run a command called: `find $PATH -type f -size +1M` (with the `$PATH` expanded). As there is no such command you get the error.

Your quotes should be outside the `$(...)`

```
    echo "$(find $PATH -type f -size +1M)"
```

Better still, drop the `echo` as it is not required:

```
    find $PATH -type f -size +1M
```

---

As @alexcs notes, you shouldn't use `PATH` as a variable name because it is already used by the system (in fact you shouldn't use any all-caps variable name) and you should quote its use as the user may have provided something containing whitespace:

```
    read -p  "Enter the path for log files: " LogPath
    # ...
    find "$LogPath" -type f -size +1M
```

---

Consider:

```
echo $("echo '1..4..7'; echo 'a  b  c'")

"echo '1..4..7'; echo 'a  b  c'"

echo $(echo '1..4..7'; echo 'a  b  c')

echo "$(echo '1..4..7'; echo 'a  b  c')"

echo '1..4..7'; echo 'a  b  c'
```

Comment: ```
#!/bin/bash


DISK_USAGE=$(df -h /dev/xvda1 | awk '{gsub("%","");print $5}' | tail -1)
THRESHOLD=20


if [ $DISK_USAGE -ge $THRESHOLD ]
then
        read -p  "Enter the path for log files: " PATH
        echo "Below is the list of large files which are taking space:"
        find "$PATH" -type f -size +1M


fi
```
Above solution is giving the below error:
```
Enter the path for log files: /var/log
Below is the list of large files which are taking space:
./list-large-files: line 12: find: command not found
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-53:~$

```